# El vs La for Feminine Noun

Tags: pronunciación, género

Sometimes, we use el before a feminine noun, e.g. 'agua', 'ama', 'hambre' and the reason for the same is that the word starts with 'a' (or 'ha') and we do not want to have two 'a' one after another. This article describes it well -

[Substitution of 'La' by 'El'](https://www.thoughtco.com/substituting-el-for-la-3079094)

However, this article also says that when the 'a' is not stressed, we use 'la' instead, for example 'la habilidad', 'la audiencia' etc. Here, I am getting a little confused, since there is no accent over 'agua', 'ama' etc., how would I know if that 'a' (or 'ha') in the beginning of the word is stressed or not?

Comment: @DGaleano I get the feeling that the OP's problem is not knowing the rules for stressed syllables rather than not knowing that we say _el agua_.

Comment: @mdewey if that is the case then there is no posible answer we can give him here... or perhaps we can point him in the direction of a question regarding the stress syllable and use of the «tilde». What do you think ?  In any case, this one can be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there are many exceptions, most of them described in [this article](https://www.rae.es/dpd/el), the examples in the question are easy to answer. The general rule is:

- When the first syllable is stressed, it has a masculine article: el `a`gua, el `a`ma, el `ham`bre, el `an`sia, el `al`ma.
- When the first syllable is unstressed, it has a feminine article: la
  habili`dad`, la au`dien`cia, la ac`ción`, la agili`dad`, la an`gus`tia.

Exceptions: el a`mor`, el am`bien`te, el ac`ce`so, el antece`den`te, el asis`ten`te ...

Comment: Why are amor, ambiente, antecedente, and asistente exceptions? They are of the masculine gender, so obviously require the masculine article.

Answer (score 5):

The written accent is only used when the word does not follow the usual rule for placing stress in Spanish words. Basically the stress falls on the last syllable unless that ends with a vowel. For this purpose final -n or -s are ignored.

So  'agua', 'ama', 'hambre' all have a final syllable ending in a vowel so are stressed on the one before it and hence take el. Your other examples are not stressed on the first syllable.

Comment: Great answer. English also has lexical stress where the stress can differentiate one word from another (insight (/ˈɪnsaɪt/) vs incite (/ɪnˈsaɪt/)). The only difference is that Spanish has a fixed rule that a majority of words follow and when they don't an accent is added to mark the exact place of stress. In English we leave it unmarked, another reason why ESL is hard.

Answer (score 1):

**Planteamiento:** *Aquí, me estoy confundiendo un poco, ya que no hay acento. sobre 'agua', 'ama', etc., ¿ cómo sabría si esa 'a' (o 'ha') al principio de la palabra está acentuada o no?*

*Here, I am getting a little confused, since there is no accent over 'agua', 'ama' etc., how would I know if that 'a' (or 'ha') in the beginning of the word is stressed or not?*

---

Para enfatizar lo que dice Danielillo quiero añadir al contexto, y que quizás sea parte de la cuestión. Como el acento prosódico (sílaba con más fuerza en la pronunciación), determina a su vez cual es dentro de una la palabra, la sílaba que con más fuerza se pronuncia (tónica) y por contra, cuales son dentro de esa misma palabra las sílabas que tienen menos intensidad (átona).

Por tanto para no confundirte con lo que llamamos en Español "acento", y puedas distinguir el "acento y sus tipos" entre las palabras que llevan y no lleven tilde, será bueno prestar atención a las siguientes diferencias y de esta forma reconocer los tipos de "acentos", a los que Danielillo ha intentado referirse al explicar tu pregunta;

- Acento Prosódico.
- Acento Ortográfico. (Con tilde)

---

- **Explicación General**.

Digamos en términos generales que todas las palabras se pronuncian o tienen acento.

- **El Acento Prosódico** es una fuerza especial ó hincapié que se hace en la pronunciación de la sílaba tónica dentro de una palabra, este hincapié ó fuerza la llevan todas las palabras, aunque no todas marquen en forma de tilde ó con tilde    " ´ ", su sílaba más intensa.

Dentro de la palabra distinguiremos entre sílaba tónica y sílabas átonas.

Las sílaba tónica es la sílaba que se pronuncia con más fuerza (acento prosódico) dentro de cada palabra. En ella encontraremos el acento prosódico.

¿ Dónde se encuentra la sílaba tónica (acento prosódico) en las siguientes palabras?

Ejem. Casa - **Ca**sa / Pensar - Pen**sar** / Involucrar - Involu**crar** / Rezar - Re**zar**

Diremos entonces que las otras partes de la palabra son sílabas átonas, ya que tienen menos intensidad en la pronunciación.

Ejem. Casa - Ca *sa* / Pensar - *Pen* sar / Involucrar - *Involu* crar / Rezar - *Re* zar

- **El Acento Ortográfico**

Una vez que reconozcamos y determinemos cual es el acento prosódico, sabremos cual es la sílaba tónica, es decir, la que posee más fuerza en la pronunciación dentro de la palabra. Una vez adquirido el hábito podemos pasar a la siguiente fase de la acentuación ó marcación con tilde y aprender cuales son las reglas y excepciones que rigen los acentos en Español.

Estas reglas de acentuación están formuladas de tal manera que permiten saber siempre de manera inequívoca cuál es la sílaba tónica de una palabra.

*Reglas de acentuación en Español*

https://www.spagnolofirenze.it/reglas-de-acentuacion-del-espanol/